# CronTab for logging not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I am testing a simple logger command to put in a crontab. When I run **php artisan schedule:run** command I am able to get the desired output at first. But the crontab to run everyMinute() does not work.

My Crontab entry is *** * * * * cd /Users/bikrambhandari/My Documents/Laravel Projects/Migration/artisan && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1**

My scheduling code is as follows

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('visa:expire')
            ->everyMinute();
    }
```

For now the command **php artisan visa:expire** code will write a line in log file. I am on mac. And want to have log file written every minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your scheduling code is fine, I'd guess your cron job isn't being called properly due to the spaces in your directory path that you are CD'ing to.

Change your crontab line:

```
 * * * * * cd "/Users/bikrambhandari/My Documents/Laravel Projects/Migration/artisan" && php artisan schedule:run >> "/Users/bikrambhandari/My Documents/crontab.log.txt" 2>>"/Users/bikrambhandari/My Documents/crontab-error.log.txt"
```

The quotes will let the spaces NOT act as an argument delimiter, so the `cd` should succeed, and then php will kick off.  I changed the redirect of output from `/dev/null` to a file - this is where you can look to see if your actual `schedule` function has issues.  Once you know it is all working, change the redirect back to `/dev/null`

Edit -

Changed redirect again, to simplify it and generate separate log files.

I'd also add a line to just touch a file so you know `cron` is really running -

```
 * * * * * touch /tmp/cron_is_running
```

Comment: Its still not working. I cannot see any crontab.log.txt file in My Documents directory\

Comment: @Bikram is `cron` even running?  Note that due to you being on a Mac (I'm a linux guy) I didn't check the redirection.  I'll edit and put it some definite stuff :) one sec

Comment: I cannot see cron file being generated.

Comment: It's working now. Actually, the crontab was looking for a directory. But artisan is an executable file. I fixed by removing artisan from the path.

Comment: @Bikram actually, `cd` was looking for a directory :)

Comment: My bad day. Learnt new thing